# Changing layer names in WMS served from ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, wms

I have published a number of wms layers with ArcGIS Server (AGS) 10.0. Although I have named the layers logically in the mxd and named the wms service accordingly, the wms GetCapabilities document still names the layer 0,1,2,3 etc. There is no way to change these names in AGS Manager. I have tried to name them differently in the GetCapabilities Doc but this creates problems when trying to display the layer because AGS can´t reference the layers.

How do I name the layers differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select the option *Use layer names from the map document* in the Add New Service  - Capabilities form.

Take a look at the OneGeology WMS cookbook [Setting up an ArcGIS Server WMS](http://www.onegeology.org/wmsCookbook/5_2_1.html) that shows you how to do this.

Comment: will this work for server 10.4 for feature access services? I do not see this option

Comment: Not sure about 10.4.

Comment: Has this changed in ArcGIS Server 10.8.1? We are getting a different <name> where spaces are replaced with _ and a suffix 5-digit number is concatenated.